# Apache spark joining a DataFrame to itself via relation DataFrame yields empty result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a strange problem with Apache Spark (using the Scala API). There are two DataFrame objects, let's call them **beans** and **relation**.

1. The **beans** dataframe consists of two columns, named **id** and **data**. Consider that all **id**s are unique and **data** holds a text representation of some *action* or a *target* of an action.
2. The **relation** DataFrame defines relationship between the *action*s and their *target*s. It consists of two columns: **actionId** and **targetId**

*(look at the code snippet below to view a table represantation of the DataFrame objects)*

Basically, I am trying to alias the **beans** as two new DataFrame objects: **actions** and **targets** and then join them via the **relation** DataFrame

Here's some code to illustrate what is going on:

```
//define sql context, using 
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)

// ...

// Produce the following DataFrame objects:
// beans:                   relation:
// +--------+--------+      +----------+----------+
// |   id   |  data  |      | actionId | targetId |
// +--------+--------+      +----------+----------+
// |   a    |  save  |      |    a     |     1    |
// +--------+--------+      +----------+----------+
// |   b    | delete |      |    b     |     2    |
// +--------+--------+      +----------+----------+
// |   c    |  read  |      |    c     |     3    |
// +--------+--------+      +----------+----------+
// |   1    |  file  |
// +--------+--------+
// |   2    |   os   |
// +--------+--------+
// |   3    |  book  |
// +--------+--------+
case class Bean(id: String, data: String)
case class Relation(actionId: String, targetId: String)
val beans = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    Bean("a", "save") :: Bean("b", "delete") :: Bean("c", "read") ::
    Bean("1", "file") :: Bean("2", "os") :: Bean("3", "book") :: Nil
  )
val relation = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    Relation("a", "1") :: Relation("b", "2") :: Relation("c", "3") :: Nil
  )


// alias beans as "actions" and "targets" to avoid ambiguity
val actions = beans as "actions"
val targets = beans as "targets"
// join actions and targets via relation
actions.join(relation, actions("id") === relation("actionId"))
        .join(targets, targets("id") === relation("targetId"))
        .select(actions("id") as "actionId", targets("id") as "targetId",
                 actions("data") as "action", targets("data") as "target")
        .show()
```

The **desired** output of this snippet is

```
// desired output
// +----------+----------+--------+--------+
// | actionId | targetId | action | target |
// +----------+----------+--------+--------+
// |    a     |    1     |  save  |  file  |
// +----------+----------+--------+--------+
// |    b     |    2     | delete |   os   |
// +----------+----------+--------+--------+
// |    c     |    3     |  read  |  book  |
// +----------+----------+--------+--------+
```

However, the **real** (and strange) output is an empty DataFrame

```
+--------+--------+------+------+
|actionId|targetId|action|target|
+--------+--------+------+------+
+--------+--------+------+------+
```

I have suspected that there is an issue with joining a DataFrame to itself, but the example in [Usage of spark DataFrame “as” method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537420/usage-of-spark-dataframe-as-method) proves this suspicion wrong.

I am working with Spark 1.4.1 and Scala 2.10.4 but got the same result on Spark 1.5.1 and Scala 2.11.7

Changing the schema of the DataFrame objects is not an option. Any suggestions?

## Solution

Refer to [zero323's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33079674/5435888). If you are getting an error message like this

```
error: value $ is not a member of StringContext
              actions.join(relation, $"actions.id" === $"actionId")
                                     ^
```

be sure to add the following statement

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between what you do here and an example you've linked. In the linked answer I use `Column` objects directly, here you use `apply` method on a `DataFrame`. To see the difference just type both in a REPL:

```
scala> actions("actions.id")
res59: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = id

scala> col("actions.id")
res60: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = actions.id
```

For an alias to be properly recognized you have to use `Column` objects directly otherwise alias is simply stripped. It means you need query like this:

```
actions.join(relation, $"actions.id" === $"actionId")
  .join(targets, $"targets.id" === $"targetId")
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col 

actions.join(relation, col("actions.id") === col("actionId"))
  .join(targets, col("targets.id") === col("targetId"))
```

to make it work. Of course using `col` on the RHS is strictly optional here. You could have use `apply` as before.

If you prefer to use `apply` you can rename join columns:

```
val targets = beans.withColumnRenamed("id", "_targetId")
val actions = beans.withColumnRenamed("id", "_actionId")

actions.join(relation, actions("_actionId") === relation("actionId"))
  .join(targets, targets("_targetId") === relation("targetId"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I would split it in two phases, so:

```
val beans = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  Bean("a", "save") :: 
  Bean("b", "delete") :: 
  Bean("c", "read") ::
  Bean("1", "file") :: 
  Bean("2", "os") :: 
  Bean("3", "book") :: 
  Nil
)
val relation = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  Relation("a", "1") :: 
  Relation("b", "2") :: 
  Relation("c", "3") :: 
  Nil
)

// "add" action
val step1 = beans.join(relation, beans("id") === relation("actionId"))
  .select(
    relation("actionId"), 
    relation("targetId"), 
    beans("data").as("action")
  )

// "add" target column
val result = step1.join( beans, beans("id") === relation("targetId"))
  .select( 
    step1("actionId"), 
    step1("targetId"), 
    step1("action"), 
    beans("data").as("target")
)

result.show
```

### Remark

Still, it seems unusual and smelly to keep the different beans ("a", "b", "c") in the same table as ("1", "2", "3")