# UDF in Spark SQL DSL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, dsl

I am trying to use DSL over pure SQL in Spark SQL jobs but I cannot get my UDF works.

```
sqlContext.udf.register("subdate",(dateTime: Long)=>dateTime.toString.dropRight(6))
```

This doesn't work

```
rdd1.toDF.join(rdd2.toDF).where("subdate(rdd1(date_time)) === subdate(rdd2(dateTime))")
```

I also would like to add another join condition like in this working pure SQL

```
val results=sqlContext.sql("select * from rdd1 join rdd2 on rdd1.id=rdd2.idand subdate(rdd1.date_time)=subdate(rdd2.dateTime)")
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL expression you pass to `where` method is incorrect at least for a few reasons:

- `===` is a `Column` method not a valid SQL equality. You should use single equality sign `=`
- bracket notation (`table(column)`) is not a valid way to reference columns in SQL. In this context it will be recognized as a function call. SQL uses dot notation (`table.column`)
- even if it was neither `rdd1` nor `rdd2` are valid table aliases

Since it looks like column names are unambiguous you could simply use following code:

```
df1.join(df2).where("subdate(date_time) = subdate(dateTime)")
```

If it wasn't the case using dot syntax wouldn't work without providing aliases first. See for example [Usage of spark DataFrame "as" method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31537420/1560062)

Moreover registering UDFs makes sense mostly when you use raw SQL all the way. If you want to use `DataFrame` API it is better to use UDF directly:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val subdate = udf((dateTime: Long) => dateTime.toString.dropRight(6)) 

val df1 = rdd1.toDF
val df2 = rdd2.toDF

df1.join(df2, subdate($"date_time") === subdate($"dateTime"))
```

or if column names were ambiguous:

```
df1.join(df2, subdate(df1("date_time")) === subdate(df2("date_time")))
```

Finally for simple functions like this it is better to compose built-in expressions than create UDFs.

Comment: thanks a lot. What do you mean by composing built-in expressions ? Using "substr" like functions from sql.Column package ?

Comment: More or less. Theres are some subtleties there (not every function is implemented using expression) but lets not dwell on that. If this helps please don't thank - just accept and/or upvote :)